# Kmeans clustering for sift features

Tags: python, k-means

NOTE: This is my first ever stackexchange question. I'm sorry if the way I put my question was not as expected. So, here goes my doubt.

I have a data set of about 3000 images. I performed sift (scale invariant feature transform) for all those images (using David Lowe's sift demo) and have obtained the images' respective (3000) keypoint features. Now I have to perform the k-means clustering for the 3000 images' keypoint features. Each image has its own keypoints  (changes from image to image) and they are in a 128 dimensional matrix. Now for me to perform the k-means, these 3000 sift vectors must be put together, and they should be trained to obtain one k-means model from it.

For example:

The images were converted to .pgm format before sift, and here are the 226 keypoints for one of the images after performing sift:

```
74 128

98.20 126.13 16.47 2.776

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 12 1 0 0 0 0 0 39 9 0 0

0 15 24 12 29 1 0 0 0 27 92 33 13 1 0 0 0 0 0 20

83 90 19 1 2 6 3 19 165 86 2 0 1 8 44 88 24 0 3 21

8 24 165 64 3 1 4 0 0 1 1 18 116 23 10 0 1 14 11 51

165 101 9 20 5 1 5 84 38 24 28 157 40 5 10 14 0 3 5 0

0 0 0 0 45 101 16 0 0 0 0 1 114 165 17 8 1 0 0 1

7 56 17 46 26 0 0 0
```

(likewise the remaining keypoints and their 128 dimensions continue till the 226th keypoint features).

Likewise the remaining 2999 images have their respective keypoint features.

Now I have to perform the k-means clustering for the entire 3000 images' sift features and get one k-means model from them. I am planning on using k-means package from scikit  (sklearn). How to input these 3000 images' keypoints in scikit? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to instantiate a `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` object and call `fit(X)` where X is a matrix with all keypoints of all images stacked up. For example, if rather than your 3000 images you only had two images with say 100 and 50 keypoints respectively, X would be 150 by 128. After you run `fit`, you should look at the object's attribute `cluster_centers_`, which would correspond to the k-means model you would have trained.

What is not clear from your question, though, is whether you already have the keypoints of each image represented in python as matrix. You may want to take a look at [their k-means example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html#example-cluster-plot-kmeans-digits-py).

Answer (score -2):

I trained around 64000x128 keypoints on an EC2 c3.4xlarge cluster with 16 cores. I used Ipython parallel with Scikit learn and it took around 120 hours for clustering. This could be one solution. Basically X to the fit function should be the numpy array of shape (number_of_features X 128) .